# Error with the query in Oracle

Tags: sql, asp.net, oracle, oracle10g

I am using `Oracle` and using in my **toad** to check what the result is. But I am getting error as

> ORA-01740: missing double quote in identifier

Here is my query

```
SELECT T1.Project_Id, 
       PROPERTY_NAME Project_name,
       T1.Vehicle_No,
       T1.Creation_date,
       T1.Time_In,
       T1.Time_Out
FROM 
       XXCUS.XX_SUPINV T1
   INNER JOIN XXACL_PN_PROJBUILD_V T2 
       ON T1.Project_Id = T2.Project_id
WHERE  t1.Project_Id = '" + ddlProjectName.SelectedValue + "' 
   AND Creation_date BETWEEN to_date fnd_conc_date.string_to_date('"TxtIndate.Text"') AND 
         to_date fnd_conc_date.string_to_date('"txtOutDate.Text"')"
```

Please suggest where I am mistaking

Comment: is this your final constructed query? `to_date()` has to be like `to_date('20-Jan-2015','DD-Mon-YYYY')` .. your date conversion here is bit confusing

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar: Yes, I tried in my Toad but giving error

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar: OK let me edit and check

Comment: There seems to be an unmatched `"` at the very end of your statement... (to start with...)

Comment: @Abecee: can you please help me with the correct query.

Comment: Could you drop the very last `"` from your query, re-run, and share the database's response? I'd expect `to_date` to cause an error as well. What does `fnd_conc_date.string_to_date('"TxtIndate.Text"')` return (value and datatype)? Perhaps you can drop the two `to_date` altogether. And depending on your table structure you might need to qualify `Creation_date` in `AND Creation_date BETWEEN`.

Comment: @Abecee: I will test it and let you know in some time as the power connection is not working and servers are down

Comment: @Abecee: I tried with this query: `SELECT T1.Project_Id,PROPERTY_NAME Project_name, T1.Vehicle_No,T1.Creation_date,T1.Time_In,T1.Time_Out 
FROM XXCUS.XX_SUPINV T1 INNER JOIN XXACL_PN_PROJBUILD_V T2 ON T1.Project_Id = T2.Project_id 
WHERE  t1.Project_Id = '" + 409 + "' AND 
Creation_date BETWEEN to_date fnd_conc_date.string_to_date('"01-jan-2015') AND to_date 
fnd_conc_date.string_to_date('"01-jan-2012"')` and I am getting error as `Missing keyword`

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar: Yes, please help. Still getting the error

Comment: You could try `SELECT
  T1.Project_Id,
  PROPERTY_NAME Project_name,
  T1.Vehicle_No,
  T1.Creation_date,
  T1.Time_In,
  T1.Time_Out
FROM XXCUS.XX_SUPINV T1
INNER JOIN XXACL_PN_PROJBUILD_V T2
  ON T1.Project_Id = T2.Project_id
WHERE t1.Project_Id = 409
  AND Creation_date BETWEEN to_date('01-jan-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND to_date('01-jan-2012', 'DD-MON-YYYY')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the actual Query (with data) you're trying to execute.

```
SELECT T1.Project_Id, 
       PROPERTY_NAME Project_name,
       T1.Vehicle_No,
       T1.Creation_date,
       T1.Time_In,
       T1.Time_Out
FROM 
       XXCUS.XX_SUPINV T1
   INNER JOIN XXACL_PN_PROJBUILD_V T2 
       ON T1.Project_Id = T2.Project_id
WHERE  t1.Project_Id = '409' 
   AND Creation_date BETWEEN to_date('01-jan-2015','DD-mon-yyyy') AND 
         to_date('01-jan-2012','DD-mon-yyyy')
```

You're programmatic version could be ( Just derived from your base version)

```
 sl =  "SELECT T1.Project_Id, 
           PROPERTY_NAME Project_name,
           T1.Vehicle_No,
           T1.Creation_date,
           T1.Time_In,
           T1.Time_Out
    FROM 
           XXCUS.XX_SUPINV T1
       INNER JOIN XXACL_PN_PROJBUILD_V T2 
           ON T1.Project_Id = T2.Project_id
    WHERE  t1.Project_Id = '" + ddlProjectName.SelectedValue + "' 
       AND Creation_date BETWEEN fnd_conc_date.string_to_date('" + TxtIndate.Text+ "') AND 
             fnd_conc_date.string_to_date('"+ txtOutDate.Text +"')"
```

> To improve readability and avoid [`SQL*Injection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx),you should [try
>   using bind variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790424/usage-of-oracle-binding-variables-with-like-in-c-sharp)( I am not so thorough with the `.NET` syntax)

Comment: The first one is working fine in the oracle, but the second one is giving error as `;` as expected `(fnd_conc_date.string_to_date('"TxtIndate.Text"')`

Comment: `string_to_date()` is your function  in `asp.net`?

Comment: No, i guess it is used in oracle to call dynamically

Comment: @nad in that case, you don't need `to_date()` , assuming with the name.. it returns date itself..

Comment: @nad I did my editing with my iPad.. extremely difficult!! this should work now.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, let me check now

Comment: For the second one, now I am getting error as `missing keyword`.

Comment: Do you have the printed SQL Query .. formed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82365/discussion-between-maheswaran-ravisankar-and-nad).

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you have additional `"` in the end of query:

```
to_date fnd_conc_date.string_to_date('"txtOutDate.Text"')" -- here
```

should be like:

```
to_date fnd_conc_date.string_to_date('"txtOutDate.Text"')
```

> An initial double quote (") was found without a closing quote. If an
>   identifier contains a blank or special characters other than $, #, or
>   _, it must be enclosed in double quotes.

[Documentation](http://ora-01740.dbquanti.eu/)

Comment: can you help me with full query, as still i am getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Turning a comment into an answer...</sup>

You might want to verify first, the data is actually flowing from the database to your front end. For this, verify a simplified query to return data in, e.g., TOAD. Then just copy the query string to your application code, and send it from there to the database. Try something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
  T1.Project_Id,
  PROPERTY_NAME Project_name,
  T1.Vehicle_No,
  T1.Creation_date,
  T1.Time_In,
  T1.Time_Out
FROM XXCUS.XX_SUPINV T1
INNER JOIN XXACL_PN_PROJBUILD_V T2
  ON T1.Project_Id = T2.Project_id
WHERE t1.Project_Id = 409
  AND Creation_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-jan-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                    AND TO_DATE('01-jan-2012', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Please comment, if and as adjustment / further detail is required.